# How to get the value a complex (nested) property via parsing expression in a razor helper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a razor helper for rendering a tree-view dropdown.
I'm trying to make is similar to the `DropDownFor` helper for easy and familiar use in the views.
Is there away to parse the value of the model property provided via an expression, other than `DataBinder.Eval()`?

Previously I could solve the problem by using the `PropertyInfo.GetValue` method, but it's having problems with retrieving the value of a property which is a collection that I'm foreaching using the indexer:
`model => model.SettingsModel.Categories[i].CategoryKey`

```
public static ITreeViewDropdown<ITreeViewItem> TreeDropDownFor<TModel, TProperty, ITreeViewItem>(
            this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
            Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
            IEnumerable<ITreeViewModel<ITreeViewItem>> tree,
            string optionLabel,
            object htmlAttributes = null)

        {
            if (expression == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(expression));
            }

            TModel model = (TModel)html.ViewContext.ViewData.ModelMetadata.Model;

            var memberExpr = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
            if (memberExpr == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"Expected body of type '{typeof(MemberExpression).Name}' but received '{expression.Body.GetType().Name}'", nameof(expression));
            }

            MemberInfo propertyMember = memberExpr.Member;
            string propertyName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);

            if (propertyMember.MemberType != MemberTypes.Property)
            {
                throw new MemberAccessException($"{propertyName} must be a property");
            }

            // An alternative is needed here
            var propertyValue = DataBinder.Eval(model, propertyName);

            return new TreeViewDropdown<ITreeViewItem>(html, tree, propertyName, propertyValue, optionLabel, htmlAttributes);
        }
```

The above solution currently works for what I need:

`@Html.TreeViewDropdownFor(m => m.SettingsModel.Categories[i].CategoryKey, Model.CategoryTree, "Please Select")`

But I [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.databinder.eval?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_UI_DataBinder_Eval_System_Object_System_String_) that the Eval() method can be slow and I want to do it the 'right' way, and I can't think of how else to get the value of `SettingsModel.Categories[i].CategoryKey`. I can easily get the value I need if the expression provided is simpler, e.g.

`m = > m.ProjectViewModel.CategoryKey`, but not with collections and indexer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`expression.Compile().Invoke(model)` actually gets the correct value. Considering the types are generic, I don't think it's going to get better than this